# How to reduce spacing on special command for \section

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I have a command:

```
\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}
```

I use this command to separate my titles, but I want less spacing between Education and work experience. Currently it looks like this:

```
\NewPart{Education}{}
\EducationEntry
{University of Test}
{Test 2018}
{\begin{itemize} \itemsep -1pt
    \item Test
    \end{itemize}}

%%% Work experience
\NewPart{Work Experience}{}
```

**Output:**

[image: Resume latex]

I want the space between Work experience and the last line of education to decrease.

Whole latex code to play around with:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}  % Colours by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
  \textheight=700px
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Allow arbitrary font sizes
\usepackage{textcomp}

%% Define a new 'modern' style for the url package that will use a smaller font.
\makeatletter
\def\url@modernstyle{
  \@ifundefined{selectfont}{\def\UrlFont{\sf}}{\def\UrlFont{}}}
\makeatother
\urlstyle{modern} %% And use the newly defined style.

\frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{                 % Change font of \section command
  \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%   % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{2pt}}
  %\titlespacing*{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}
  %\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{3pt}}

%%% Macros
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\spacebox}
\settowidth{\spacebox}{8888888888}      % Box to align text
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}   % Vertical space macro

\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
    \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan (optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}
%\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}

\newcommand{\PersonalEntry}[2]{
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
    \parbox{\spacebox}{                  % Box to align text
    \textit{#1}}                      % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
    \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}              % Entry value

\newcommand{\SkillsEntry}[2]{                % Same as \PersonalEntry
    \noindent\hangafter=0 % Indentation
    \parbox{\spacebox}{                  % Box to align text
    \textit{#1}}                    % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
    \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}              % Entry value

\newcommand{\AwardsEntry}[2]{                % Same as \PersonalEntry
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 % Indentation
    \parbox{\spacebox}{                  % Box to align text
    \textit{#1}}                    % Entry name (birth, address, etc.)
    \hspace{1.5em} #2 \par}              % Entry value

\newcommand{\EducationEntry}[4]{
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Study
    \colorbox{White}{
      \parbox{8.5em}{
      \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par  % Duration
    \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % School
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\WorkEntry}[4]{       % Same as \EducationEntry
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
    \colorbox{White}{%
      \parbox{12em}{%
      \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par   % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % Company
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\ProjectEntry}[4]{
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
    \colorbox{White}{%
      \parbox{25em}{%
      \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par   % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % Company
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\ProjectEntryTwo}[4]{
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \hfill      % Jobname
    \colorbox{White}{%
      \parbox{10em}{%
      \hfill\color{Black}#2}} \par   % Duration
        \noindent \textit{#3} \par        % Company
    \noindent\hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}
%\newcommand{\ProjectEntry}[4]{         % Similar to \EducationEntry
  %  \noindent \textbf{#1} \noindent \textit{#3} \hfill {#2} \par
   % \noindent \small #4 % Description
    %\normalsize \par}

\newcommand{\AwardEntry}[4]{         % Similar to \EducationEntry
    \noindent \textbf{#1} \noindent \textit{#3} \hfill {#2} \par
    \noindent \small #4 % Description
    \normalsize \par}
    \begin{document}
\MyName{\centerline{Sample Name}}
\NewPart{Education}{}
    \EducationEntry
    {University of Test}
    {Test 2018}
    {\begin{itemize} \itemsep -1pt
        \item Test
        \end{itemize}}

    %%% Work experience
    \NewPart{Work Experience}{}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting code fragments, can you please put your fragments into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: @AlanMunn thank you for the info, does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}` before \newpart...

```
%%% Work experience
\vspace{-2\baselineskip} % 
\NewPart{Work Experience}{}
```

And I get this:

[image]

Is the result you're looking for?

PSD: You forgot to put `\end{document}` xD

Comment: Exactly was I was looking for, thank you so much! And haha yes you're right.